# Change <select> options with javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, if-statement, select

Can I use a javascript if/else function to change the select options of a form? I don't want to use CSS to hide/display different dropdown menus, so here is what I've ccome up with:

```js
function getType() {
  var x = document.getElementById("food").value;
  var items;

  if (x === "fruit") {
    items = "Apple" || items = "Oranges" || items = "Bananas";
  else {
    items = "Eggplants" || items = "Olives"
  }
  document.getElementById("pickone").value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="food">

 <select id="pickone">
   <option id="1"></option>
   <option id="2"></option>
 </select>
```

I can't seem to find any documentation about how to do this, so any help would be great.

Comment: `items = "Apple" || items = "Oranges" || items = "Bananas";` what do you want to achieve here?

Comment: i think i got it - you want to change the select options depending on what you typed into the input field

Comment: This may help: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp

Comment: the double pipe symbol || represents an OR statement in JavaScript, it does not delaminate a list of items.

Comment: Actual proper [**SelectElement Add**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add) documentation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could append a string for the `options` and set it as `innerHTML` of your select field afterwards:

```js
function getType() {
  var x = document.getElementById("food").value;
  var items;
  if (x === "fruit") {
    items = ["Apple", "Oranges", "Bananas"];
  } else {
    items = ["Eggplants", "Olives"]
  }
  var str = ""
  for (var item of items) {
    str += "<option>" + item + "</option>"
  }
  document.getElementById("pickone").innerHTML = str;
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", getType)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="food">
<button id="btn">click</button>
<select id="pickone">
</select>
```

Comment: This is great - exactly what I was hoping for. When I copy the code though, it doesn't seem to work.  Is there a script library it is dependant on?

Comment: To clarify, I have no problems with the html portion, but the clicks eems to do nothing when I'm testing it in notepad

Comment: @PhysicsIsRelativelyCool no, there is no library needed. If you paste the `HTML` code and the `js` this should work. If not you've missed something

Comment: Yep, you're right! Your code works perfectly, I had to load the script after the select element, rather than in the <head>

Answer (score 10):

Your logic is not very right, specially where you try to do this 
`items = "Apple" || items = "Oranges" || items = "Bananas";` 
with the above statement you are saying that `itens` are Apple OR Oranges OR Bananas, only one at once...
you'll need an array of elements, like this: 
`var itens = ["Apple", "Oranges", "Bananas"];`
Then, you will need to loop through it to add them to the select, like this:

```js
var itens = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"];
var selectElem = document.getElementById("mySelect");

for (var i = 0; i < itens.length; i++){
  var item = itens[i];
  var element = document.createElement("option");
  element.innerText = item;
  selectElem.append(element);
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

With that, now you can achieve what you want, just follow this logic... 
you can also, if you want, add an `if` statement to check what is the input value, then set the options based on the input value, as you are already trying to do.

Comment: @messerbill OP asks how to dynamically add items to a select. This answer showcases that very clearly. OP can hook that logic up their own code. Answer do not need to contain copy paste solutions. If anything they never should.

Answer (score 4):

You can change options easily with JavaScript. I would advise to use an additional library to ease DOM manipulation, such as [JQuery](https://jquery.com/). An example code would look like the example below. You have to make sure to define an event on which the options should be changed. The example *listens* to changes within the input field.

```
<input type="text" id="food" value="vegetables"/>
<select id="pickone"></select>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var fruits = ["Apple", "Oranges", "Bananas"];
var vegetables = ["Eggplants", "Olives"];

vegetables.forEach(function(item){
    $('#pickone').append("<option>" + item + "</option>");
});

$('body').on('keyup', '#food', function (){
    if ($('#food').val() === 'fruits') {
        $('#pickone').html("");
        fruits.forEach(function(item){
            $('#pickone').append("<option>" + item + "</option>");
        });
    }
});

</script>
```