# How can I update select options based on selected radio button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an assignment for my class, and we have to create a website that has 4 different radio buttons, but with each of those buttons, there is a drop down list with different options for each button. I am struggling trying to figure out how to put this into JavaScript.

There are 4 days you have to select from: day 1, day 2, day 3 and day 4. day 1 and day 3 have times of 2pm, 5pm, and 8pm; while day 2 and day 4 have times of 1pm and 4pm.

This is the code I have so far:

```js
function onLoad() {
  //method for button times
  var select = document.getElementById("day1");
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("2:00 PM", "2pm");

  var select = document.getElementById("day1");
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("5:00 PM", "5pm");

  var select = document.getElementById("day1");
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("8:00 PM", "8pm");

  var select = document.getElementById("day2");
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("1:00 PM", "1pm");

  var select = document.getElementById("day2");
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("4:00 PM", "4pm");
}
```

This is the relevant portion from the index.html file:

```html
<h2>Choose Your Date</h2>
<input type="radio" value="sat_feb8" name="date1" id="day1" onclick="onLoad();" checked="checked">
<label for="size1">Saturday, February 8</label>
<br>

<input type="radio" value="sun_feb9" name="date1" id="day2" onclick="onLoad()">
<label for="size2">Sunday, February 9</label>
<br>

<input type="radio" value="sat_feb15" name="date1" id="day1" onclick="onLoad()">
<label for="size3">Saturday, February 15</label>
<br>

<input type="radio" value="sun_feb15" name="date1" id="day1" onclick="onLoad()">
<label for="size4">Sunday, February 16</label>
<br>
```

I called the `onLoad` function for each of the buttons in the index page.
Thank you!

Comment: why don't you create the `dropdowns` in `html` itself?

Comment: should I create the drop downs for each of the two days? How would I get one set of times to display over the other?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: @DanielSchroederDev not true, because all the inputs have the same `name` attribute.

Comment: You can remove the `id` attribute from the `inputs` you don't need it. The logic in `onLoad` should be: get the value of `date1` (I'm sure you'll find the way), then,  [set the options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49114766/863110) based on the logic you described in your question. Try to follow that logic and if you have follow up questions, [mention me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/303669)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating the `dropdown` with `js`, add them directly in the `html` using `select`. You can create containers for each `radio` button and add `change` event. When change event is triggered, you can show it's dropdown by getting the parent of clicked radio button and then the `select` element within it. Then change it's display style to block.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input')
  .forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('change', function() {
      document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(select => select.style.display = "none");
      const selectEle = this.parentElement.querySelector('select');
      selectEle.style.display = "block";
    });
  });
  
  document.querySelector('input:checked').parentElement.querySelector('select').style.display = "block";
```

```css
select {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Choose Your Date</h2>
<div>
  <input type="radio" value="sat_feb8" name="date1" id="day1" checked="checked">
  <label for="size1">Saturday, February 8</label>

  <select>
    <option value="2pm">2:00 PM</option>
    <option value="5pm">5:00 PM</option>
    <option value="8pm">8:00 PM</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" value="sun_feb9" name="date1" id="day2">
  <label for="size2">Sunday, February 9</label>
  <select>
    <option value="1pm">1:00 PM</option>
    <option value="4pm">4:00 PM</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" value="sat_feb15" name="date1" id="day3">
  <label for="size3">Saturday, February 15</label>

  <select>
    <option value="2pm">2:00 PM</option>
    <option value="5pm">5:00 PM</option>
    <option value="8pm">8:00 PM</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" value="sun_feb15" name="date1" id="day4">
  <label for="size4">Sunday, February 16</label>
  <select>
    <option value="1pm">1:00 PM</option>
    <option value="4pm">4:00 PM</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample code. You can have two groups of radio buttons and show/hide based on day selection. Hope this helps.

```js
function onLoad() {
  //method for button times
  var group1 = document.getElementById("group1");
  group1.classList.remove('hide');
  group1.classList.add('show');
  
  var group2 = document.getElementById("group2");
  group2.classList.remove('show');
  group2.classList.add('hide');
}


function onLoad2() {
  //method for button times
  var group2 = document.getElementById("group2");
  group2.classList.remove('hide');
  group2.classList.add('show');
  
  var group1 = document.getElementById("group1");
  group1.classList.remove('show');
  group1.classList.add('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Choose Your Date</h2>
<input type="radio" value="sat_feb8" name="date1" id="day1" onclick="onLoad();">
<label for="size1">Saturday, February 8</label>
<br>

<input type="radio" value="sun_feb9" name="date1" id="day2" onclick="onLoad2()">
<label for="size2">Sunday, February 9</label>
<br>

<input type="radio" value="sat_feb15" name="date1" id="day1" onclick="onLoad()">
<label for="size3">Saturday, February 15</label>
<br>

<input type="radio" value="sun_feb15" name="date1" id="day1" onclick="onLoad2()">
<label for="size4">Sunday, February 16</label>
<br>

<h2>Choose Time</h2>
<div id="group1" class="hide">
<select>
<option>2 PM</option>
<option>5 PM</option>
<option>8 PM</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="group2" class="hide">
<select>
<option>1 PM</option>
<option>4 PM</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but how do i get it do the times are in a drop down list ant not radio buttons?

Comment: Is there a way to put the styling in the div (the style="display") into the css so it isnt in the html?

Comment: @student0562, Updated with using the css classes.