# how can i create a dropdown list using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Which code should I use so that I can create a dropdown list using Javascript or Jquery just like where I have to create a dropdown list for country and state and cities? Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BLAST FURNACE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
    .spad{
        padding: 80px;
    }
    #my_image{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .cont{
        width: 700px;
        height: 700px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>BLAST FURNACE SIMULATION</h1>
<p>BLAST FURNACE SIMULATION PROCESS.</p>
<!-- <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    <span class="spanloader">

</span>
</canvas> -->
<!-- <button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
CLICK HERE TO  CHARGE IRON ORE FLUX INTO BLAST FURNACE.</button> -->
<!-- <input type="button" id="btnnext" value="CLICK HERE TO  CHARGE IRON ORE FLUX INTO BLAST FURNACE" /> -->
<!-- <script>
var img=document.createElement("img");
img.src
</script> -->

<div class="cont">
    <div class="row spad">
        <img id="my_image" src="#"  class="img-fluid"/>
    </div>
    <span class="spanloader">
        <span>set Loading Image Image</span>
    </span>
</div>    


<input type="button" id="btn01" value="CLICK HERE TO SHOW EMPTY BLAST FURNACE " />
<input type="button" id="btn02" value="CLICK HERE TO CHARGE IRON ORE FLUX INTO BLAST FURNACE" />
<input type="button" id="btn03" value="CLICK HERE TO SHOW BLAST FURNACE" />
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#btn01').click(function () {       
        $("#my_image").attr("src", "empty.png");
    });
    $('#btn02').click(function () {       
        $("#my_image").attr("src","Sequence01_1.gif");
    });
    $('#btn03').click(function () {       
        $("#my_image").attr("src", "BLASTFURNACE.png");
    });

</script>
</html>
```

Here I want to create a dropdown list to select from country and after selecting country another dropdown list of cities should appear.

Comment: Where is your `<select>` tag with a list of countries? That part is basic HTML.

Comment: See this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) for `select` `option`s. While you might need JavaScript to retrieve and handle the data, the basic markup is all HTML as @kmoser noted

Comment: it is just an example ...i want to use something different here .

Comment: What do you mean by _something different_ ? Based on your writing, I assume you'd want a dropdown list of countries and a separate dropdown list of cities, and based on which country is selected, the city list will dynamically change, correct?  Yes, you'd need JavaScript for basic logic, but nonetheless you'd need `select` and `options` HTML elements to render them.

Comment: Do you mean that you want “a more beautiful” option for a drop down?

Comment: i just want to create a drop down list in which user have to select only one time from the given options and the other data is dynamically pre fetched as per given options.

Comment: @BumhanYu yes i want to create a drop down list where it will dynamically change when user selects from the given options.

Comment: In your scripts near the bottom of your code you're using Bootstrap 4 Bundle and Bootstrap 5. I should pick one or the other, that would be best. Bootstrap has it's own drop down functionality so JS would not be needed in any way usually (except for those Bootstrap links of course). Here is the standard Bootstrap 5 Nav, you could simply copy paste it. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Comment: [This tutorial post](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/select/paired.php) talks about exactly what you're describing. Also this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49114766/7216508) addresses a similar request.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const sampleArr = [
    {id: 1, name: "test"},    {id: 1, name: "test"},
    {id: 1, name: "test"},
    {id: 1, name: "test"},
    {id: 1, name: "test"},
    {id: 1, name: "test"},
  ]
  
  if(sampleArr) {
   $("#stateLint").css({ display: "block" });
   sampleArr.map(sam => {
    $("#countryName").append( $(`<option>`, {
                value: sam.id,
                text: sam.name,
              }))
  })
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "stateLint" style="display: none">
  <select id="countryName"></select>
</div>;
```

You can do this like that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).